# Why do power tools generally use brushed motors?

Tags: brushless-dc-motor

Why do power tools (such as hand drills, angle grinders, etc.) generally use brushed motors instead of brushless motors? To understand, this is really not clear in a sentence or two.

Comment: In a sentence, BLDC is many times more expensive than DC motor.

Comment: Good enough for most end users and cheaper to produce.

Comment: If you remove the links from your question, the question stays the same, but won't be spammy.

Comment: Links removed. Links to your own site constitutes spam and is not acceptable. IF you mention that the site is yours (usually in an answer) AND the linkage has value to the site it MAY be acceptable. I've removed the links. Please do not repeat.

Answer (score 3):

Two reasons: brushed motors are cheap, brushed motors wear out.

Brushed motors don't need any intelligence to control them. You put voltage across the contacts, supply enough current and it turns. BLDC motors require some method to know current rotor position (either with some kind of sensor or using back e.m.f in a sensor-less design). Then you need intelligence to work out when to power which coils, then you need fast enough switching for each of the coils. There is can be an order of magnitude in the cost of the motor. The closest I've seen was with a brushed DC motor that was around $2, the BLDC alternative we were offered was $12 and significantly less powerful.

Brushed motors have brushes which wear out. Conspiracy theories aside, a company wants people to come back and buy more to make money in the long run. Consumers have been taught that things break after 2-5 years. BLDC motors can run until the bearings wear out, which with good bearings can be measured in decades. Brushed motors will quote lifetime in 1000s of hours. Brushes could be made replaceable, but that requires spending money on design.

We shall have to see what impact the right to repair movement and environmental concerns have on this.

Comment: Of course, many brushed motors *do* have replaceable brushes.

Answer (score 3):

As a supplement to the other answers, high speed tools such as vacuums and angle grinders will use series wound dc motors to achieve high speed operation - which of course must have brushes.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to give some more nuance to your claim : cheap power tools usually use brushed motors. In recent high end professional tools, you often find brush-less motors.

Why this difference?

First of all, brushed DC motors are cheap, and if you power them from battery and need only one speed level, then you don't even need any electronics (excepted battery protection, which is often done in the battery itself). Even if you need some speed control, it is very simple and cheap. So for cheap tools, it's the only way to go.

On the other hand, brushless DC motors require extra sensing (ideally with hall sensors, or at least with current sensors), require to control 3 phases, ... so as soon as you want a brushless DC motor, you directly have a big cost overhead : this might be OK for expensive professional tools, but most customers don't want to pay 100$ more just to have a brushless motors.

Brushless motors also have a somewhat better efficiency (which is a pro if running on battery) and much longer lifetime (which doesn't maters for most people that will use the tool each other year, and probably destroy it my mis-use rather than by wear of the motor ; but which maters a lot for professionals using the tool each day).

So either you want a cheap tool for occasional use, and you usually get cheap brushed DC motors, or you accept to pay 5 times the price for a good professional tool, and you can hope for a brushless motor. It's up to you

Answer (score 1):

brushed motors also have high torque at all speeds, even when stalled, which you can't get with most other motors without complicated electronics.